# PrimeNg multiselect chips in multiselect position

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a problem with chips position in multiselect from PrimeNg.
I need to change styling to make it smaller

```
 <div style="height: 10%; margin: 15px">
  <p>Wybierz kandydatow</p>
  <p-multiSelect
    [virtualScroll]="false"
    [style]="{'display':'flex','height':'100%','width':'100%', 'flex-wrap': 'wrap'}"
    display="chip" [options]="schemes" optionLabel="name">
  </p-multiSelect>
</div>
```

And i have something like this
[View in the modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbS5U.png)

Answer (score 0):

you need to style the component which is encapsulated.
you need to break the encapsulating by using `ng-deep`
in your `.css` file try this

```
::ng-deep p-multiselect-label{
  // your style
}
```

you need to find the right CSS class that prime-ng set to the element you  want to change

good luck :)